# MVC Controller Action via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a large scale MVC application. It was running as a portal for some years within our organization. However we now have some other applications that will interact with this portal.

For instance, we want our application to authenticate a user coming from a different application (the username and passwords are the same in both applications).

I changed my LoginController to include the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AjaxLogin(string username, string password)
{
    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    loginModel.UserName = username;
    loginModel.Password = password;
    if (Login(loginModel) == true)
    {
        return Json( new { Result = loginModel}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Invalid login. Please try again.";
    return Json(new { Result = "ERROR" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The LoginModel has two properties, UserName and PassWord.
To test login, I created a sample html file and added the following script to it.

```
     <script>
        var urlservice = "http://localhost:4941/";
        $.ajax({
                url: urlservice + 'Login/AjaxLogin',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {username : "progr1", password : "Xmb@092"},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
        </script>
```

When I run this html I get the following error:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:4941/Login/AjaxLogin?username=progr1&password=Xmb@092
```

However when I put the same in the browser and hit enter I get the following result:

> {"Result":{"UserName":"progr1","PassWord":"Xmb@092"}}

My question is, do I have the right approach for the sort of interaction between two portals sharing the data?

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

your Url is wrong use this code for generate yor action url

```
  <script>

    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AjaxLogin","Login")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {username : "progr1", password : "Xmb@092"},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to call this from a separate file which is outside the scope of this application. What I am trying to do is check if this action executes from a different website or not. I have to make my website work this other portal So when the user logs in to their portal he will also login to my portal. So I created an html file to check if it works or not

Comment: @progrAmmar Do you publish your application on iis or iis express ?

Comment: I am testing this on IISExpress. Having said that, when it will get published it will be on a different URL than those which will be accessing it. For instance, if my site is on www.mysite.com/Login, the other site which will make login calls to my site will be on www.theothersite.com

Comment: if you host your application you can use www.theothersite.com/controllername/actionname...for test host your aplication on iis and check your code

Comment: OK I checked what you said, now the error is this

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: If you have @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your view Remove it

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Url.Content("~")` to get your Domain URL

then your javascript code will something like::

```
 var urlservice = @Url.Content("~");
        $.ajax({
                url: urlservice + 'Login/AjaxLogin',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {username : "progr1", password : "Xmb@092"},
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
```

If you will use `@Url.Action("AjaxLogin","Login")` then for your local execution this will work but will give a problem when you will publish your project on server.

Comment: What I am trying to do is check if this action executes from a different website or not. I have to make my website work this other portal So when the user logs in to their portal he will also login to my portal. So I created an html file to check if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Ajax approach doesn’t allow cross domain communication due to security reasons.

As you are expecting json data then **jsonp** (JavaScript Object Notation with Padding) is a way to grab JSON data from external domains

More over jsonp is a better and cleaner alternative to other approaches (web proxy and IFrame) to get data from an external domain.

Refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy) article this will help you